# Problem with temperature using microcanonical in a small system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I have a system with two particles and three energy levels, with energy $\epsilon$, 2$\epsilon$ and 3$\epsilon$. The second level is degenerated. I want to find an expression like E(T) or T(E) where E is energy and T is temperature. So I calculate the microstates and then use $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$. The problem is that the energy is not continuous so I do not know if I can calculate the partial derivative. I thought that this can be solved using numerical methods to give each energy a temperature. But I do not know if this is accurate. I also do not know how to interpret the result. What happens if the system has a temperature between two energies? For example, putting in contact with a reservoir.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the system to be isolated (and closed), You can use a [microcanonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble). According to which
$$S=k_B\ln \Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is a number of microstates accessible to the state.

---

If the system is closed but not isolated so that there can be energy fluctuation, then you can use a [canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble). You can determine the partition function
$$Z=\sum_{\text{state} \ i}g_ie^{-\beta E_i}$$
From which average energy can found using
$$U=-\frac{d\ln Z}{d\beta}$$

---

See the following for more details

- [Microcanonical Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble)
- [Canonical Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble)